# Is there sequence $ (a_n) $ s.t. $ a_n \rightarrow 0 $ ,$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \neq 0 $, and $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow L $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Does there exist a sequence $ (a_n) $ s.t. it satifies $ a_n \rightarrow 0 $ ,$  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \neq 0 $, and also $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow L \in \mathbb{R} $ ( Meaning the limit is a finite number )?

I tried to assume that such a sequence does exist and reach a contradiction but got stuck. So now I am not sure if the statement's actually true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such sequence does not exist!

**By contradiction**: assume that $a_n\to 0$, with $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $a_n \neq 0$, and $\frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow L \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, by definition of the second limit, for $\epsilon>0$, eventually $\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-L\right|<\epsilon$, and
$$\frac{1}{|a_n|}\leq \left|\frac{1}{a_n}-L\right|+|L|< \epsilon+ |L|\implies |a_n|>\frac{1}{|L|+\epsilon}.$$
Hence, as $n\to +\infty$ we get the contradiction
$$0=\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_n|\geq \frac{1}{|L|+\epsilon}>0.$$

Answer (score 2):

No.

$a_n\to 0\iff\dfrac{1}{\big|a_n\big|}\to \infty$.

Comment: So if $ a_n \rightarrow 0 $ and $ \forall n. a_n \neq 0 $. Then $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow \infty $ or  $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow -\infty $ or $ \frac{1}{a_n} $ does not converge( if we take the sequence $ a_n = \frac{ (-1)^n}{n} $ ) ? ( I mean, are these the only possibilities in general )